# You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async Django

Tags: python, django, async-await

I'm making a telegram bot. That's why I use asynchronous methods in django.

```
@dp.message(Command('habits'))
async def handle_habits(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    profile = await TelegramProfile.objects.aget(chat_id=chat_id)
    user = profile.user

    await bot.send_message(chat_id, text=user - {user}')
```

I get an error when I call the last line: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
How to fix it?

Comment: What is `send_message` doing?